# Will a IDisposable be disposed if the using block returns?

Tags: c#, .net, return, idisposable, using

For example

```
using(var something = GetSomething())
{
    something.DoSomething();
    if(something.IsX()) return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting one, you're doing a GetSomething() and not a New Something. I don't think the framework has intelligence to distinguish the diff. If Something is a singleton you might get "DisposedObject" exceptions after exiting. You could build a small test app to find out what the framework does with a Using(GetSomething()).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. The `Dispose` method is called however the `using` statement is executed, unless it was an abrupt whole-process termination. The most common cases are:

- A `return` within the block
- An exception being thrown (and not caught) within the block
- Reaching the end of the block naturally

Basically a `using` statement is mostly syntactic sugar for a `try`/`finally` block - and `finally` has all the same properties.

EDIT: From section 8.13 of the [C# 4 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc):

> A `using` statement is stranslated into three parts: acquisition, usage, and disposal. Usage of the resource is implicitly enclosed in a `try` statement that includes a `finally` clause. This `finally` clause disposes of the resource.

The `finally` statement is described in section 8.10 of the specification:

> The statements of a `finally` block are always executed when control leaves a `try` statement. This is true whether the control transfer occurs as a result of normal execution; as a result of executing a `break`, `continue`, `goto` or `return` statement; or as a result of propagating an exception out of the `try` statement.

Comment: I know you're Jon Skeet, but can you cite a reference, please? :)

Comment: @Louis: Impossible - all of the documentation references Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Florian: I've overwritten your edit with the most relevant quotes of the specification. The OP can read the spec for more details.

Comment: @Louis: I've added quotes from the spec. Hopefully that'll do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[`using` is syntactic sugar for a try/finally block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The using statement ensures that
>   Dispose is called even if an exception
>   occurs while you are calling methods
>   on the object. You can achieve the
>   same result by putting the object
>   inside a try block and then calling
>   Dispose in a finally block;

[In the documentation on the `finally` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Whereas catch is used to handle
>   exceptions that occur in a statement
>   block, finally is used to guarantee a
>   statement block of code executes
>   regardless of how the preceding try
>   block is exited.

So, the `using` gets translated to `try/finally`, with `.Dispose()` in the `finally` part, ensuring that it is always executed no matter what happens in the try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using is a compiler feature, which expands to

```
try {
  ...
  return ...;
}
finally {
  foo.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the using block will dispose of the object as soon as it exits scope.

Eg, when true is returned, the next statement is outside of scope so the variable will be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think as soon as the control will go out of `{}` dispose will be called so in short `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

One point not yet mentioned is that while a "return" within a "using" block will call Dispose on the controlled variable, a "yield return" from within a "using" block within an iterator will not Dispose the controlled variable unless the IEnumerator associated with the iterator is Disposed.